# RichTextBlock keeps inserting spaces between Runs in UWP

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp

I have this very simple `RichtTextBlock`:

```
    <RichTextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Paragraph>
            <Run Text="Hello" />
            <Run Text="world" />
        </Paragraph>
    </RichTextBlock>
```

In design time, the Runs appear without a space between them (**that is what I need!**), but in runtime, both Runs are separated by a space.

To illustrate the problem, here are the snapshots:

In the Visual Studio designer, this how it renders:
[image: Correct behavior]

That for me it's the correct behavior.

However, in run time, it renders like this:

[image: Bad behavior]

**How do I make the Runs join together instead of being spaced??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, having read the post by Pieter Nijs, I've created a Behavior for UWP that works for Universal Windows apps.

```
public class RemoveEmptyRunsBehavior : Behavior<RichTextBlock>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        RemoveWhitespaceRuns(this.AssociatedObject);
    }

    private void RemoveWhitespaceRuns(RichTextBlock tb)
    {
        var tuples = from p in tb.Blocks.OfType<Paragraph>()
            from r in p.Inlines.OfType<Run>()
            where r.Text == " "
            select new { Paragraph = p, Run = r };

        foreach (var tuple in tuples)
        {
            tuple.Paragraph.Inlines.Remove(tuple.Run);
        }
    }
}
```

The usage is very simple: Attach it to the RichTextBlock you want the extra spaces to be removed.

```
<RichTextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Paragraph>
        <Run Text="Hello" />
        <Run Text="world" />
    </Paragraph>

    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:RemoveEmptyRunsBehavior />
    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</RichTextBlock>
```

Don't forget to add the XAML behaviors for UWP (from NuGet): **Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed**

and to add this namespace prefix declaration!

```
xmlns:interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
```

Answer (score 2):

Pieter Nijs has created an attached property to fix this!
Details are up on [his blog here...](http://blog.pieeatingninjas.be/2016/11/19/getting-rid-of-whitespaces-between-runs-in-a-textblock/)

In short it will get all the text available from the runs and will get rid of the spaces it finds before pushing out the text.

```
var spaces = tb.Inlines.Where(a => a is Run 
        && ((Run)a).Text == " "
        && !GetPreserveSpace(a)).ToList();
    spaces.ForEach(s => tb.Inlines.Remove(s));
```

Comment: It seems it works only with TextBlock. In UWP we use RichTextBlock and it seem it has a different structure. For example, it doesn't have "Inlines", but "Blocks". Can you post the code for RichTextBlock? :) Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ow... no, sorry was actually unaware that there would be a difference with the RichTextBlock and the regular TextBlock O_o

Comment: Yes, it seems it works a bit differently. I'm trying myself right now, but I don't know how this will end. If you are so kind to make it work for RichTextBlock, it would be awesome!

Answer (score 2):

Cool, didn't know that -like Glenn said- there would be such a difference between `TextBlock` and it's `Rich` nephew ;-).

Updated my code to work with the `RichTextBlock` (might need some additional tweaking, but it seems to work in the provided scenario).

```
public class RichTextBlockExtension
{
    public static bool GetRemoveEmptyRuns(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(RemoveEmptyRunsProperty);
    }

    public static void SetRemoveEmptyRuns(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(RemoveEmptyRunsProperty, value);

        if (value)
        {
            var tb = obj as RichTextBlock;
            if (tb != null)
            {
                tb.Loaded += Tb_Loaded;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException();
            }
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RemoveEmptyRunsProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("RemoveEmptyRuns", typeof(bool),
    typeof(RichTextBlock), new PropertyMetadata(false));



    public static bool GetPreserveSpace(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(PreserveSpaceProperty);
    }

    public static void SetPreserveSpace(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(PreserveSpaceProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PreserveSpaceProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("PreserveSpace", typeof(bool),
    typeof(Run), new PropertyMetadata(false));


    private static void Tb_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var tb = sender as RichTextBlock;
        tb.Loaded -= Tb_Loaded;

        foreach (var item in tb.Blocks)
        {
            Paragraph p = item as Paragraph;
            if(p!=null)
            {
                var spaces = p.Inlines.Where(a => a is Run
                   && ((Run)a).Text == " "
                   && !GetPreserveSpace(a)).ToList();
                            spaces.ForEach(s => p.Inlines.Remove(s));
            }
        }
    }
}
```